# User Stories about Automated tasks, who is the user?

Tags: user-story

Following the formal user story style:

> As `<user>`, I want `<goal>` so that `<benefit>`.

How can stories be written when there isn't an obvious user-interaction taking place, as in the case of automated processes like nightly invoicing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What's wrong with e.g.:

> As a sales assistant, I want the system to generate my invoices raised during the day, that night without my interaction so that time is saved.

Think of who will use the **results** of the process.

Comment: Also "As an accountant, I want to review the invoices generated nightly to confirm the dollar volume and count" and "As a sales associate I want to review the invoices generated nightly to confirm that all my sales are invoiced correctly" or "As a customer service rep I want to see the automatically generated invoices so that I can review them with a customer."  There are an unlimited number of stories based on an internal, automated process.  The details of the automated process are an appendix to the story.

Comment: Hmm, do we even need to specify overnight? i.e. As a user I want the system to generate my invoices automatically

Comment: @Murph, depends on what Programming Hero's users need.

Comment: @Murph: Excellent observation.  They have to be generated just before the person wants to look at them.  Whether that's overnight or "just in time" is a separate set of decisions.

Comment: @StuperUser hmm, there may be constraints that suggest that things need to be done overnight - that I have no issue with... its more that one needs to avoid making any assumptions

Answer (score 2):

Just give the thing a name as "AutomaticInvoicer". See it as a robot that acts as a person. No big difference there. Maybe use "it" instead of "I" to make the distinction clear.

> ```
> As <AutomaticInvoicer>, it wants to search for open invoices so that
> it can initiate booking.
> ```

Comment: I bet if they looked for what started Skynet, they'd find a story that sounded like this :)